# bootstrap proportion confidence interval

Tags: r, function, statistics-bootstrap

I would like to produce confidence intervals for proportions using the boot package if possible. 
I have a vector and I would like to set a threshold and then calculate the proportions below the specified level.
After that I would like to use the bootstrap function in the boot package to calculate the confidence intervals for the proportions. 
Simple example of what I have so far:

```
library(boot)

vec <- abs(rnorm(1000)*10) #generate example vector

data_to_tb <- vec

tb <- function(data) {
  sum(data < 10, na.rm = FALSE)/length(data) #function for generating the proportion
}

tb(data_to_tb)

boot(data = data_to_tb, statistic = tb, R = 999)
quantile(boot.out$t, c(.025,.975))
```

However, I get this error message:

```
> boot(data = data_to_tb, statistic = tb, R = 999)
Error in statistic(data, original, ...) : unused argument (original)
```

I can not get it to work though, help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your function `tb` - it needs two arguments. From the help file `?boot`

> **statistic**  A function which when applied to data returns a vector
>   containing the statistic(s) of interest. When sim = "parametric", the
>   first argument to statistic must be the data. For each replicate a
>   simulated dataset returned by ran.gen will be passed. In all other
>   cases statistic must take at least two arguments.

Comment: Look at the help file. In particular, the `statistic` entry and the examples at the bottom.